# how to render django haystack search results in formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-haystack

I am using haystack for search.  I need to allow the user to add additional data to search entries after a search and so I believe I need to use the search results in a formset or list of forms.

For example when search for food I would be able to add the serving size:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not contain enough information for a detailed answer but based on the information you've given I would suggest you take a look at creating unbound forms using the Django [Formfactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) and populating them with data.

You can then use these populated forms in the way you requested.

I'll give you some example code to get you started:

```
    def _create_form_instances(self, model_name=None, exclude=None):
        """Creates an form instance for the provided model_name"""

        for content_type in self.content_types:
            if model_name == content_type._meta.object_name:
                form = modelform_factory(content_type, exclude=exclude)

                return form

     #The following code comes from a different function:

     unbound_form = self._create_form_instances(
                    model_name=item._meta.object_name,
                    exclude=('page', 'content_html'))

                instance_to_form_mapping = {'content': item.content}

                bound_form = unbound_form(instance_to_form_mapping)
```